# How can I update a JavaFX progress bar from RxJava Flowable?

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have the following reactive code:

```
//JavaFX ProgressBar
ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(0);

Flowable
        .fromIterable(itemList)
        .parallel()
        .runOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map(item -> {
            Thread.sleep(1000); //imitate expensive computation
            return item.getCode();
         })
         .sequential()
         .observeOn(JavaFxScheduler.platform())
         .subscribe(result -> {
             System.out.println(result);
          });
```

I want to update the ProgressBar on every iteration of the flowable.

I thought of something like this:

```
int i= 0; //increment on every iteration
int total = itemList.size(); //total number if items in List
progressBar.setProgress((float)(i / total));
```

However, I could not figure out how to increment the variable `i` at the end of every iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just increment i in the subscription

```
AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
Flowable
    .fromIterable(itemList)
    .parallel()
    .runOn(Schedulers.io())
    .map(item -> {
        Thread.sleep(1000); //imitate expensive computation
        return item.getCode();
     })
     .sequential()
     .observeOn(JavaFxScheduler.platform())
     .subscribe(result -> {
         i.increment();
         progressBar.setProgress((float)(i.get()/itemList.size))
         System.out.println(result);
      });
```

Comment: To be accessible from subscription, `i` should be final. final variable can't be incremented.